java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class kafka.server.KafkaConfig$
We were using spring-boot v3.2.0, spring kafka v3.1.0 and kafka_clients v3.6.1 and everything was working perfectly fine without any issues. I tried uplifting these to the latest version available in maven for spring-boot v3.2.4, spring kafka v3.1.3 and kafka_clients v3.7.0 and now the code is compiling but the test are failing with following error for one package :
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext for [WebMergedContextConfiguration@38320819 testClass = com.oracle.wsa.authvalidation.AuthHelperTest, locations = [], classes = [com.oracle.wsa.WebSocketAgentApplication], contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles = [], propertySourceDescriptors = [], propertySourceProperties = ["org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true"], contextCustomizers = [org.springframework.kafka.test.context.EmbeddedKafkaContextCustomizer@56284a6c, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.observability.ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer@1f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizer@d5e575c, org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@1cd6b1bd, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@7a388990, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@7e52a26b, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestAnnotation@5bf73b6a], resourceBasePath = "src/main/webapp", contextLoader = org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader, parent = null]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:180)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:191)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:130)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:260)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class kafka.server.KafkaConfig$
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:825)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:344)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.lambda$loadContext$3(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137)
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:58)
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:46)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.withHook(SpringApplication.java:1454)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader$ContextLoaderHook.run(SpringBootContextLoader.java:553)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:225)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:152)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class kafka.server.KafkaConfig$
    at kafka.server.KafkaConfig.DeleteTopicEnableProp(KafkaConfig.scala)
    at org.springframework.kafka.test.EmbeddedKafkaKraftBroker.addDefaultBrokerPropsIfAbsent(EmbeddedKafkaKraftBroker.java:256)
    at org.springframework.kafka.test.EmbeddedKafkaKraftBroker.afterPropertiesSet(EmbeddedKafkaKraftBroker.java:202)
    at org.springframework.kafka.test.context.EmbeddedKafkaContextCustomizer.customizeContext(EmbeddedKafkaContextCustomizer.java:130)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader$ContextCustomizerAdapter.initialize(SpringBootContextLoader.java:443)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.applyInitializers(SpringApplication.java:627)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:400)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:333)
    ... 21 more

Similar error was seen in another package as well :
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext for [WebMergedContextConfiguration@52238861 testClass = com.oracle.wsa.WebSocketAgentApplicationTests, locations = [], classes = [com.oracle.wsa.WebSocketAgentApplication], contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles = [], propertySourceDescriptors = [PropertySourceDescriptor[locations=[], ignoreResourceNotFound=false, name=null, propertySourceFactory=null, encoding=null]], propertySourceProperties = ["wsa.fuzzing=true", "org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true"], contextCustomizers = [org.springframework.kafka.test.context.EmbeddedKafkaContextCustomizer@56284a6c, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.observability.ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer@1f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizer@d5e575c, org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@1cd6b1bd, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@7a388990, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@7e52a26b, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestAnnotation@5bf73b6a], resourceBasePath = "src/main/webapp", contextLoader = org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader, parent = null]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:180)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:191)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:130)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:260)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.apache.kafka.server.common.MetadataVersion org.apache.kafka.server.common.MetadataVersion.latestProduction()'
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:825)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:344)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.lambda$loadContext$3(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137)
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:58)
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:46)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.withHook(SpringApplication.java:1454)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader$ContextLoaderHook.run(SpringBootContextLoader.java:553)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:225)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:152)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.apache.kafka.server.common.MetadataVersion org.apache.kafka.server.common.MetadataVersion.latestProduction()'
    at kafka.server.Defaults$.<clinit>(KafkaConfig.scala:156)
    at kafka.server.KafkaConfig$.<clinit>(KafkaConfig.scala:763)
    at kafka.server.KafkaConfig.DeleteTopicEnableProp(KafkaConfig.scala)
    at org.springframework.kafka.test.EmbeddedKafkaKraftBroker.addDefaultBrokerPropsIfAbsent(EmbeddedKafkaKraftBroker.java:256)
    at org.springframework.kafka.test.EmbeddedKafkaKraftBroker.afterPropertiesSet(EmbeddedKafkaKraftBroker.java:202)
    at org.springframework.kafka.test.context.EmbeddedKafkaContextCustomizer.customizeContext(EmbeddedKafkaContextCustomizer.java:130)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader$ContextCustomizerAdapter.initialize(SpringBootContextLoader.java:443)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.applyInitializers(SpringApplication.java:627)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:400)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:333)
    ... 21 more

I found out that only specific version combination of spring-boot, spring-kakfa, kafka-clients works well but I am not able to find anything on the newer version 3.7.0.
I would like to know the actual issue and a possible solution for this.

You can find a compatibility matrix here:
https://spring.io/projects/spring-kafka
According to it, with spring boot 3.2.X you should be using  kafka_clients 3.6.0 and spring kafka 3.1.X.
Clients 3.7.0 will most likely go with spring boot 3.3.X.
